# How do I stop Emacs from automatically editing my startup file?

Tags: emacs

Emacs edits my `.emacs` file whenever I use the customization facility, or when I type a command that is disabled by default.  Any automatic editing of my configuration makes me nervous.  How can I stop Emacs from ever editing my `.emacs`. file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first thing to do is to stop that silly "disabled command" feature from ever doing anything.  If you care this much about your `.emacs` file, you certainly don't need `novice.el` bossing you around.

```
(setq disabled-command-function nil)
```

The customization facility can be made to stuff all your customizations in a separate file with the following commands.

```
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs-custom.el")
(load custom-file 'noerror)
```